# Joomla form method post strips away diacritics

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a Joomla module with form:

```
<form id="ContactForm"  action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_k2&view=search&layout=search&Itemid=1303');?>" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Vyhledat: <input type="text" name="searchKey" value="" style="width: 400px;"/>
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Vyhledat" /><br />

</td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```

And I use POST method to get the data to the destination.
I "catch" them with:

```
 $foo = JRequest::getString('searchKey');
```

When I search for words without diacritics (adam, andy, anything) it works perfect. However it is a Czech site and it uses diacritics so when I try to search for Jiří, the letters ř and í are stripped away and it is using only JI.

My question is: Why does it do that and how to fix that?

Comment: have a look at this. it might be of some use to you ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499474/how-can-i-test-if-an-input-field-contains-foreign-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla get string method will remove special characters

Read this Official Joomla's Doc

http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_and_Filtering_GET_and_POST_requests_with_JRequest::getVar

with JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW will solve your prblem

Comment: stupid stupid stupid -> I am because I was trying to figure this out half of my day,.. now I know how to get this done. Thank you so much!